# Compiled queries and "Parameters cannot be sequences"

Tags: linq-to-sql, contains, linq.compiledquery

I thought that compiled queries would perform the same query translation as DataContext.  Yet I'm getting a run-time error when I try to use a query with a .Contains method call.  Where have I gone wrong?

```
//private member which holds a compiled query.
Func<DataAccess.DataClasses1DataContext, List<int>, List<DataAccess.TestRecord>>
  compiledFiftyRecordQuery = System.Data.Linq.CompiledQuery.Compile
  <DataAccess.DataClasses1DataContext, List<int>, List<DataAccess.TestRecord>>
  ((dc, ids) => dc.TestRecords.Where(tr => ids.Contains(tr.ID)).ToList());

//this method calls the compiled query.
public void FiftyRecordCompiledQueryByID()
{
  List<int> IDs = GetRandomInts(50);

  //System.NotSupportedException
  //{"Parameters cannot be sequences."}

  List<DataAccess.TestRecord> results = compiledFiftyRecordQuery
    (myContext, IDs);         
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/08ccbb12-da4f-421a-8912-8fa95ebbead0/) has your answer:

> Queries with list parameters cannot be
>   precompiled because the translation of
>   the query is dependent on the number
>   of items in the list.