# Linq Compiled Queries and int[] as parameter

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, compiled, compiled-query

I'm using the following LINQ to SQL compiled query.

```
 private static Func<MyDataContext, int[], int> MainSearchQuery =
     CompiledQuery.Compile((MyDataContext db, int[] online ) =>
              (from u in db.Users where online.Contains(u.username)
               select u));
```

I know it is **not possible** to use sequence input paramter for a compiled query and im getting **“Parameters cannot be sequences” error when running it**.

On another post here [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813256/compiled-queries-and-parameters-cannot-be-sequences) ,  I saw that there is some solution but I couldn't understand it.

Does anyone know to use complied query with array as input paramter?

Please post example if you do.

Comment: Just read deeper and THEN let us know when you get stuck.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/08ccbb12-da4f-421a-8912-8fa95ebbead0/

Comment: i did :( , it is really complex and examples aren't really related to a simple requirement of passing a array as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Like the post that you referenced, it's not really possible out of the box.  The post also references creating your own query provider, but it's a bit of overhead and complexity that you probably don't need.

You have a few options here:

1. Don't use a compiled query.  Rather, have a method which will create a where clause from each item in the array resulting in something like this (psuedo-code):

   ```
   where 
       online[0] == u.username ||
       online[1] == u.username ||
       ...
       online[n] == u.username
   ```

   Note that you would have to use expression here to create each OR clause.
2. If you are using SQL Server 2008, create a scalar valued function which will take a [table-valued parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) and a value to compare againt.  It will return a bit (to indicate if the item is in the values in the table).  Then expose that function through LINQ-to-SQL on your data context.  From there, you should be able to create a CompiledQuery for that.  Note that in this case, you should take an `IEnumerable<string>` (assuming username is of type string) instead of an array, just because you might have more than one way of representing a sequence of strings, and to SQL server for this operation, it won't matter what the order is.

Comment: thx!
i couldn't make any of them work.
1) if i dont use compiled query i have no problem at all , i can just pass the int[] as parameter. maybe i miss understood what you meant.
2) i read about table-valued , but i think im getting it wrong.
i created a scalar based function that get a table-value parameter but what does it return?

Comment: @dan 1) If you don't use the compiled query at all, you still can't use Contains.  You have to split the query out into a number of OR statements 2) The scalar function with the table valued parameter would return a bit, which is 0 if the item is not contained in the table you pass in, 1 if it is.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I have found myself doing (for MS SQL 2005/2008). And I'm not sure if it is appropriate in all scenarios is to just write dynamic sql and execute it against the datacontext using the ExecuteQuery method.

For example, if I have an unbounded list that I am trying to pass to a query to do a contains...

```
' Mock a list of values
Dim ids as New List(of Integer)
ids.Add(1)
ids.Add(2)
' ....
ids.Add(1234)

Dim indivs = (From c In context.Individuals _
                    Where ids.Contains(c.Id) _
                    Select c).ToList
```

I would modify this query to create a SQL string to execute against the database directly like so...

```
Dim str As New Text.StringBuilder("")
Dim declareStmt as string = "declare @ids table (indivId int) "  & vbcrlf)

For i As Integer = 0 To ids.Count - 1

     str.Append("select " & ids(i).ToString() & " & vbcrlf)

     If i < ids.Count Then
          str.Append("union " & vbcrlf)
     End If

Next

Dim selStatement As String = "select * From " & context.Mapping.GetTable(GetType(Individuals)).TableName & _
      " indiv " & vbcrlf & _
      " inner join @ids ids on indiv.id = ids.id"

Dim query = declareStmt & str.ToString & selStatement
Dim result = context.ExecuteQuery(of Individual)(query).ToList
```

So barring any syntax errors or bugs that I coded (the above is more or less psuedo code and not tested), the above will generate a table variable in SQL and execute an inner join against the desired table (Individuals in this example) and avoid the use of a "IN" statement.

Hope that helps someone out!